# Increase or decrease amount to be withheld each pay period?

Tags: united-states, taxes

I am a recent college graduate, and this is my first time doing the Form L-4 (Louisiana's withholding tax form). On question #8, it asks "Increase or decrease in the amount to be withheld each pay period. Decreases should be indicated as a negative amount." What should I put?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know that your tax situation is not easily handled by the standard withholding table then you can use that line to ask for additional funds be withheld. You could also ask for less money to be withheld.

Why would somebody do this? They had a small side business that made them extra income, and wanted to withhold extra money from their full time job to cover the extra income. They might have been awarded a big bonus and it caused too much in taxes to be withheld so they wanted to not have as much taxes from their regular pay check.

Given the fact that you are young, in your first real job, and almost the entire tax year ahead of you, it is likely that the standard tax tables will be close enough. So leave the line blank or put zero.